# Minimization of a sum of absolute values

Tags: optimization, self-learning, absolute-value, maximum-likelihood

Let $X_{1},...X_{n}$ be a random sample with some known pdf.

I found the log likelihood. Now I would like to know how to minimise the following expression in order to minimise this likelihood and thus find the maximum likelihood estimate:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n | x_{i} - \theta | $$

I know without the absolute sign this expression would be 0 if $\theta$ = mean of the distribution.

Thoughts?

Comment: Have a look at the answer I gave [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1671334)

Comment: $\theta$ is a median of $x_i$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113270/the-median-minimizes-the-sum-of-absolute-deviations