# Finding minimum value with two variables

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives

There are some real $X_i$ values from $-1$ to $1$. What I need is to find such a new value $Y$ inside this range such that the distance from existing values $X$ inside this range to the new value $Y$ will be minimal.

So if we put it like this:
$$S_n = \frac{|X_1-Y| + |X_2-Y|+\cdots+|X_n-Y|}n,$$
where $X_1\dots X_n$ are known numbers.

How to find such an $Y$ so that $S_n$ will be minimal?

$X$ and $Y$ are numbers (integers or floats(real))

Is it multivariate calculus?

Comment: What $X$ and $Y$ are?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: X and Y are numbers (integers or floats(real))

Comment: @Name if you mean the distance between $X$ values and $Y$, then maybe you should take the absolute difference $|X_i-Y|$ instead of the signed difference $X_i-Y=-(Y-X_i)$?

The problem as it stands, is not multivariable calculus, since the $X$ values are already given, you can treat them like numbers, except, instead of having a result for an operation between $X_1$ and $X_2$, you have to keep it in the raw form, since you don't know their actual values, but they are fixed values.

The only variable here is $Y$. The current $S_n$ is decreasing in $Y$, hence minimized at $Y=1$.

Comment: And if you mean $|X_i-Y|$ instead of $(X_i-Y)$, then you want to take the *median* of the $X_i$. I expect this question has been asked and answered many times on this site.

Comment: Thanks for improvement suggestions. As I can see it Sn is also unknown. So we have two variables Y and Sn

Comment: Gerry Myerson, may be. But I am not very good with math. Can anybody give me a hint as to what math area to look into to solve this kind of equation.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318381/on-a-1-d-line-the-point-that-minimizes-the-sum-of-the-distances-is-the-median and the questions that are linked to it.

Comment: Did that help any, Name?

Comment: Are you still here, Name?

Comment: I guess not. Bye-bye, Name.